# How to import my own modules in python 3.6?

Tags: python, import, module

Let's say I have a file like:

> Project0\pizza.py
>
> Project0\make_pizza.py

and pizza:

```
def make_pizza(size,*toppings):
print("\nMaking a " + str(size)
      + "-inch pizza with the following toppings:")
for topping in toppings:
    print("- " + topping)
```

and make_pizza:

```
from pizza import make_pizza 
pizza.make_pizza(16, 'pepperoni')
```

and as shown in the codes, I want to `import pizza` into `make_pizza`, but the IDE shows up an error that there is no module named pizza. How can I solve this problem and import `pizza` into `make_pizza`?

Comment: "import pizza into make_pizza" makes no sense. `make_pizza` is a function defined *by* the module `pizza`. If `from pizza import make_pizza` fails, then you haven't configured your IDE properly to find the file `pizza.py`.

Comment: On reading this again, it's a little confusing, though, because it's not clear why you need a module `make_pizza` that calls `pizza.make_pizza`.

Answer (score 4):

You're importing it correctly, but you're calling it incorrectly.

The correct way to call it is:

```
make_pizza(16, 'pepperoni')
```

Answer (score 1):

You imported only the function `make_pizza` in your `make_pizza.py` so you can just use `make_pizza` without redefining `pizza` (since Python has already loaded this):

```
from pizza import make_pizza 
make_pizza(16, 'pepperoni')
```

As mentioned in the comments below you could use this function, but then you would need to import `pizza` and not just part of it.

Comment: Would just like to add, if you simply did `import pizza`, then your approach of using `pizza.make_pizza(16, "pepperoni")` would work.

Answer (score 0):

because the module directory is not available in the **PATH** environment variable.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is.

Comment: You can import scripts from the same dictionary

Comment: I put two .py files in the same folder "Project0"，does it means the two .py files are in the same path?

Comment: @JoJoHu  Yes there is no path problem in this case.  The problem is how you imported the module. If you did put `Project0` in the path environment variable , you could import that project from anywhere.  I.e. `import pizza` would work from any dictionary.